# How do I add a skin to the skin folder in assets in .minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I play Minecraft I cant see my skin and I figured out that it's because it isn't in the skin folder in assets, does anyone know how to put the skin in there so it can read it, or empty the folder so that it can refill with new skins?

Comment: what have you tried to get your skin to show up?

Comment: before Ive downloaded someone elses skin folder that has my skin in it and that works but its a lot of hassle

Answer (score 1):

You figured out wrong. If you ever play multiplayer, other players' clients have no clue about your assets folder so they wouldn't be able to display it, and your single-player game is in fact a multiplayer on the built-in server which is started on your own machine alongside your client, and uses the same mechanics regarding player skin as multiplayer.

Log in to your [profile at minecraft.net](https://minecraft.net/profile) and upload your skin there.

[more detailed help about player skins in Java Edition](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360034635452-Minecraft-Skins-)

Comment: Other people can see my skin but I cant and I cant see it in singleplayer either and my skin is in minecraft.net

Comment: @Mackstar And the skin you have is...? Also, type your in-game name into https://namemc.com/ and tell what skins it lists underneath.